# How can I set field level security for multiple fields in the same custom object?

Tags: administration, security, custom-field

I have deployed several objects from one sandbox environment to another. I notice that the field level security settings has not been deployed. I used the change sets method to deploy these objects.

Currently I find myself editing each field on the custom object and setting the field level security on the field.

Can this be done in mass? Is there some tip that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the profiles to your deployment set, the field level security for the fields in your deployment set for those profiles will be deployed as well.

So clone your deployment set, add all the profiles, and redeploy it. That should fix it.

Comment: Yes items like FLS, Record Type Assignment, Page Layout Assignment, Apex and Visualforce Access, etc will not be moved unless you include the Profiles along with the metadata items in your change set.